# There are fifteen triangles, what is the sixteenth?

Tags: lateral-thinking, sequence

This is "fifteen triangles":

> ▲ ▼ ▲ ▲ ▼ ▼ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▼ ▼ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▼ ?

Each triangle points up or down. What the "?" figure should be and why?

Comment: Probably a triangle, because the rest are triangles.

Comment: the next figure is "7", and there's no way to prove otherwise.

Comment: Given the "_lateral_ thinking" tag, surely the next figure is ▶ .

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It should be

> Pointing upwards

Because

> Every letter in "fifteen triangles" is represented: consonants=up, vowels=down. Since the last letter is a consonant ("s"), it should point up.

Comment: Reminds me of https://xkcd.com/169/

Answer (score 6):

On account of the lateral thinking tag, I'd say the sixteenth figure is...

> **The question mark at the end.** 
>
>  It's never stated that the sixteenth *figure* is a triangle in the title or body.

Comment: edited the question a bit

Answer (score 2):

Given the tag "lateral" thinking, I'm not sure the current pattern is enough to dictate a *single* potential pattern and so there could be a fair number of possible ways the sequence could go.

However I'll *guess* the next triangle is:

> ▼

Because:

> The pattern is reversed at the point of the second set of 2Xdown (▼ ▼)
>
>  The pattern given is:
>
> ```
> ▲  ▼  ▲ ▲  ▼ ▼  ▲ ▲ ▲  ▼ ▼  ▲ ▲ ▲  ▼
>            |ii|  |i|   |A|   |B|
> ```
>
> A = The reverse is activated
>  B = The next set of characters from being reversed at "A", which is denoted as "i"
>  ii = The next set of characters in the (now) reversed sequence

Your completed sequence would look like:

> ▲ ▼ ▲ ▲ ▼ ▼ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▼ ▼ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▼ ▼

Answer (score 0):

The sixteenth triangle is

> ▼

Because:

> The pattern at the end seems to be 2 ▼ and 3 ▲

Comment: what about the beginning of the sequence?

Comment: it's a red herring

Comment: no, it is not :)

Answer (score 0):

The next triangle is:

> ▲

Because

> The overall sequence is {1,2,3,3} UP triangles, with {1,2,2,1} DOWN triangles in between. The next group of triangles will be pointing up, since it's their turn.  There will be 2 of them in this group because their pattern sequence (reflecting the down triangle's pattern) is {1,2,3,3,2,1}.